# Change the styling of the component with props or css variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is the following block, which I put in a separate component: [img](https://hsto.org/extt/5f/76/89/5f7689c251425342606335.png)

And at certain breakpoints, I need to change its styling.
I see 2 possible normal options, but I can't figure out which one is more convenient.

1. through the props :

```js
<InfoBlock
  options={
    iconWidth: 100,
    iconMargin: 50,
    color: 'red',
    breakpoints: {
      991: {
        iconWidth: 50,
        iconMargin: 25
      },
      767: {
        iconWidth: 20,
        color: 'brown'
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

That is, in this scenario, I can essentially turn the received props inside the component itself as much as I want and change what is necessary

2. change the component styling via css variables

```js
<InfoBlock class="info-block"/>
```

```css
.info-block {
  --icon-width: 100px;
  --icon-margin: 50px;
  --color: red;

  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    --icon-width: 50px;
    --icon-margin: 25px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    --icon-width: 20px;
    --color: brown;
  }
}
```

Both options are working, and the question is, is it logical to change the css properties by using the component's propses? Just for me personally, using @media looks easier and more familiar

Answer (score 0):

I use `makeStyles` from Material UI to achieve the same.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

 anyClassName:{
  
  backgroundColor: 'red', // You can't type background-color as '-' are not accepted as variable names
  fontSize: '1Rem';
  // After doing the styling
},

AnotherClassName: {
 
 backgroundColor: 'green';
 fontSize: '0.8rem';
 
}


})

// Now we have to assign it like this

const classes = useStyles();
```

Once if we do this we can assign the class to any component we want like this.

```
<td className={classes.anyClassName}>I'm the red boi</td>

<h3 className={classes.AnotherClassName}>I'm the Green Guy</h3>
```